# Flutter Error: No named parameter with the name 'onMediaDeviceChanged'. Flutter Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, agora.io

```
Performing hot reload...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_uikit-1.1.0/lib/controllers/rtc_event_handlers.dart:140:6: Error: No named parameter
with the name 'onMediaDeviceChanged'.
  }, onMediaDeviceChanged: (deviceType) {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-6.1.0/lib/src/agora_rtc_engine.dart:1537:9: Context: Found this candidate,
but the arguments don't match.
  const RtcEngineEventHandler({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Try again after fixing the above error(s).

Performing hot reload...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_uikit-1.1.0/lib/controllers/rtc_event_handlers.dart:140:6: Error: No named parameter
with the name 'onMediaDeviceChanged'.
  }, onMediaDeviceChanged: (deviceType) {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-6.1.0/lib/src/agora_rtc_engine.dart:1537:9: Context: Found this candidate,
but the arguments don't match.
  const RtcEngineEventHandler({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Try again after fixing the above error(s).

Application finished.
```

I am creating a video calling function in my flutter app using agora. It's supposed to generate automatic tokens for every call.
I created a backend server with Node.js
But when I tried to run my application, I get an error about 'onMediaDeviceChanged'. I can't quite figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Please, have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. @giftmarimo helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like latest version of agora_uikit which is `1.1.0` is having issues with flutter latest sdk version `3.3.10`. Try downgrading your agora_uikit dependency, if you are using version 1.1.0, try downgrade to `agora_uikit: ^1.0.2` and also add `permission_handler: ^9.2.0` in your `pubspec.yml` file and then run `flutter pub get`.

Comment: I just downgraded agora_uikit

Comment: If it helps, kindly accept the answer because that's actually the solution since agora admitted on an email that the latest version has issues and their engineers are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Agora is the crappiest library I have ever came across with. Same issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are use agora_uikit package and you got these issues; you can try to remove agora_uikit package and get agora_rtc_engine. In my case fixed it. Good Luck.